# How to change the whole background in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }}
    >
      <ScrollView
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }}
      >
        <View>{renderedPreviousMessage}</View>
        <View style={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}>
          <Input />
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
```

But this renders black parts with white background:

[image: img]

How can I get the whole background to be black?

---

Edit

Here is the whole component. When I added `flex: 1`, it just made the whole screen white and everything disappeared.

```
return !message || !renderedPreviousMessage ? null : (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      // style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center" }}
      behavior="padding"
      enabled
      keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
      style={[
        cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && { backgroundColor: DARK_COLOR }
        // { flex: 1 }
      ]}
    >
      <ScrollView
        // style={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && { backgroundColor: DARK_COLOR }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      >
        <View
          style={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && { backgroundColor: DARK_COLOR }}
        >
          {renderedPreviousMessage}
        </View>
        <View
          style={[
            { paddingBottom: 50 },
            cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && { backgroundColor: DARK_COLOR }
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            inputStyle={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && styles.dark_mode_text}
            labelStyle={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled && styles.dark_mode_text}
            multiline
            label="reply"
            value={replyText}
            rightIcon={
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                  {showEmojis && (
                    <Icon
                      name="md-close"
                      type="ionicon"
                      color={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled ? WHITE : BLUE_HUE}
                      iconStyle={{
                        // paddingLeft: 20,
                        paddingRight: 20
                        // paddingTop: 10
                      }}
                      onPress={() => {
                        setShowEmojis(false);
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                  <Icon
                    name="md-send"
                    type="ionicon"
                    color={cosmetic.darkModeEnabled ? WHITE : BLUE_HUE}
                    iconStyle={
                      {
                        // paddingLeft: 20,
                        // paddingRight: 20,
                        // paddingTop: 10
                      }
                    }
                    onPress={() => {
                      if (validateLength(replyText) === 0) {
                        setReplyTooShort(true);

                        return;
                      }
                      handleSendReply(replyText);
                      setReplyText("");
                    }}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            }
            autoCorrect={true}
            errorMessage={replyTooShort ? "reply too short" : ""}
            onChangeText={e => {
              if (replyTooShort) {
                setReplyTooShort(false);
              }

              setReplyText(e);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try adding a View outside of KeyboardAvoidingView with flex:1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by realizing by Component was in another `View` of another Component, the background of which I had to change the color of. That got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: '#000' }}` for component `KeyboardAvoidingView`

Comment: That made everything disappear, now nothing is showing up and the whole background is white

Comment: You can wrap the `KeyboardAvoidingView` with a `View` component and add style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: '#000' }} to the `View` component

Comment: Same behaviour, everything is white

Answer (score 0):

Do check this out . Adding flex:1 to KeyboardAvoidingView takes the whole screen since flex is 1. so color will be applied to the whole screen. 
Expo snack working link [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/BJVrntBtr)

Ive added custom hey message since the components were not present.

Comment: Now the whole screen is white, though, and the input is gone too

Comment: did you check the link where the whole screen is black?